# How to move a child div of an image relative to the scaling of the image, when the image is scaled using object-fit:contain?

Tags: html, css

This is what I currently have:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="example.jpg">
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

img {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
object-fit: contain;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 20%;
}
```

What I would like to happen is that the overlay element stays relative to the size of the image regardless of the scaling, i.e. the top of the overlay is 10% below the top of the image and so on. However the current behaviour is that the overlay is instead relative to the container, i.e. the top is 10% below the top of the container etc. How can I fix this?

Comment: _"the overlay is instead relative to the container"_ - that is how absolute positioning works - it is relative to the closest ancestor, that has a position different from the default `static`. You would need a container that adapts to the size of the image, and put the overlay into that as well. Only with `object-fit: contain` you can't get such a container, because the dimensions of the actual image element don't change.

Comment: Is there an alternative solution then to scale the image to the container and maintain the aspect ratio?

Comment: is it possible for you to put the image as background of the container?